# MVC3: Convert "Int32 to nullable" error while POSTing nullable int by Html.Editorfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, nullable, editorfor, type-conversion

I have view model (used for filtering) with property:

```
int? Id {get;set;}
```

In my view I have sth like that:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Id)
```

When I submit form I get error:

```
Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, 
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
```

I dont want to do sth like that:

```
@Html.TextBox("Model.Id", Model.Id.HasValue ? MOdelId.Value : 0)
```

When I checked in Fiddler there is parameter ID with proper vaue but I can't even debbug because it doesn't get into Action method.

Can you help me?

PS sorry for my english

Comment: With the given code, no reason to have a Cast error. So I would suggest you to show what happens in your post action.

Comment: Could you show your POST payload as seen by Fiddler, FireBug or Chrome Developer Toolbar? Also could you show the signature of your controller action?

Comment: But It even doesn't get into my post action. It doesn't stop on my breakpoint.

Comment: @Elbar but you can see your view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the debugger to reach the breakpoint, it should first get pass the model binder. Model binder is the thing that magically binds values from your HTTP request to the model. All parsing will happen at the model binder and if it fails there, you will never hit the breakpoint in your action method.

Try the following on your view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Id, new {name = ‘Id’, id=’Id’})
```

or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Id)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is how my generated view looks like:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Filter_Id" name="Filter.Id" type="text" value="">
```

PS: i'm using many other attributes (my datetimes are nullable too) and I get ths error only when I input value in this stupid int? ;/